# Consultar datos de una tabla MySql con REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql

Lo primero que hago es capturar la variable de un formulario y mediante un fichero PHP hago la consulta. Pero de esta forma sólo me captura los IDs que no tienen asteriscos, ejemplo 123456789, necesito mostrar la información de los IDs de esta forma 123*456*789 o sólo 123*456.

**Este es el código que existe en PHP, pero sólo captura valores numéricos.**

$id = $_POST ['id'];

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM h_vida WHERE h_vida.id= '$id'";
```

**Estos son ejemplos de IDs existentes en la tabla h_vida**

[image: Ejemplo de ID´s utilizados, algunos con 5 grupos y otros con tres]

**El formulario donde se ingresa el dato a buscar no es más que un input text de html como el siguiente:**

[image: Formulario de captura del ID]

**La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:**

[image: Estructura actual de la tabla h_vida en MySql]

Sé que posiblemente me puede funcionar REGEXP, pero no sé como aplicarlo para que me llame exactamente los datos según el ID que digite, con todo y asteriscos, independientemente de la cantidad de grupos que sea.

***¿Qué debo hacer para que el código PHP mediante la consulta SQL (REGEXP) me muestre los datos de la tabla del ID con asterisco(s) digitado?***

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer una función que cada tres caracteres inserte el asterisco, te pongo un ejemplo que he estado probando y te puede valer. Es importante tratar el id como un string y no como un número para evitar errores de conversión de tipos.

```
<?php

function formateaID($id){
   $id = (string) $id;
   $formatId = null;
   $j=1;
   for($i=0; $i<strlen($id); $i++) 
   { 
     $formatId .= $id[$i];
     if($j==3){
        $j=0;     
        $formatId .= '*';
     }
     $j++;
   }
   return substr($formatId, 0, -1);
}
```

Después la llamas donde quieras pasándole tu id:

```
$id = formateaID($_POST ['id']);
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo.